# How can I compare the value of an object's attribute in Python?

Tags: python, string, object, if-statement, attributes

So, I'm using mongoDB and my queries return an array of objects. The objects look like this:

```
   {
        '_id': ObjectId('5ff891bc20cb7d29dc1d836c'),
        'Model': 'X1150',
        'Platform': 'Server',
        '# of CPU Cores': 4,
        '# of Threads': 4
    }
```

Let's say I store this specific document in the variable `doc`

Now, I want to be able to compare the 'Platform' attribute with a string. In JavaScript, for example, I would do:

```
if (doc.Platform == 'Server') return 1;
```

but it doesn't seems to work in python (maybe because the attribute is a string?). How can I make this comparison correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't Javascript - dict keys are not attributes, and indexing is not the same as dot notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you say it's returned it seems to be a dictionary , you can check it by `type(doc)`. If that's the case then `if (doc['Platform'] == 'Server') return 1;` should work

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. It's a dictionary indeed and the syntax works perfectly. Thank you George!